# Хранение данных консольного приложения на Java

Tags: java, sql, файлы

Добрый день!
На данный момент пишу не сложную консольную [программу](https://github.com/ATsurkanu/Media-manager/tree/master/src/main/java/com), которая позволяет:

1. Добавлять названия книги, музыки, фильма (три класса со String полями).
2. Присваивать им статус (Enum, + поле в тех же классах).
3. Проверять статус книги/фильма/музыки по имени.
4. Проверять, что содержится в книгах/фильмах/музыке.
5. И самое важное, после перезапуска программа должна сохранять эти данные.

Кроме того, это должен быть .jar файл, который можно запустить из консоли, и проделать все вышеописанные манипуляции.

По сути, готово всё, кроме пункта 5. На данный момент, у меня есть 3 ArrayList: books, movies, musics, в которых всё  храниться. Разумеется, что после перезапуска программы все данные исчезают.

В связи с этим, встал вопрос: как хранить всё это счастье? Писать в файлы? Подключить БД? H2 DB? Или есть более рациональный способ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Собственно, если у вас данные динамически изменяются, то хранить их в *jar* архиве или каком другом артефакте не целесообразно. Есть множество вариантов, и какой вы выберите будет зависеть только от вашего уровня знаний и возможностей.

1. Самый простой вариант это использовать стандартную или какую либо еще сериализацию и складывать данные в файл рядом с архивом.
2. Хранить данные в бд, для этого потребуется отдельно поднять базу данных.
3. Отправлять данные куда то еще. Тогда нужно будет написать отдельный сервер, который бы мог сохранять и отдавать данные по запросу.
4. Использовать облако, например *amazon, google engine, azure*

Comment: Дело в том, что я делаю тестовое задание для одной фирмы. Пытаюсь устроится на стажировку. И в Т/З указано, что человек, который будет это проверять, хочет запустить джар и пользоватся.

То есть, больше всего мне подходит вариант записи в файл, НО! я не знаю как это сделать, дабы хранить там всё, что я описал выше.
Пытался записывать туда АррейЛисты, но когда доставал их, то получал КлассКастЕксепшн.

Если Вы имеете подобный опыт чтения/записи в файл, поделитесь пожалуйста примерами, которые подойдут под мой случай. Спасибо!

Comment: Быть может, создавать отдельный файл под каждый АррейЛист?

Comment: дополните вопрос или создайте новый, с кодом и описанием того как вы это делаете. Трудно что то сказать прям вот так, но навярника там есть ошибка

Comment: Да особо добавлять нечего, вот ссылка: https://github.com/ATsurkanu/Media-manager/blob/master/src/main/java/com/Book.java

Если у Вас будет время, посмотрите пожалуйста, что там может быть не так с записью и чтением в файл.

Comment: @АнтонЦуркану мне лень было разбираться в вашем коде, накидал простой пример, сделаете по аналогии - будет работать) https://gist.github.com/izebit/315cd8642ac0436183651ae4e40a972c

Comment: И на том спасибо большое!

Скажите, а для чего вы записываете размер листа?

Comment: чтобы знать потом сколько раз нужно вызвать readObject при чтении из файла

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Сериализация заработала!

Answer (score 0):

Добрый день.

В Вашем случае хорошо подойдёт H2. Это файловая база данных, её можно положить рядом с jar и больше ничего не потребуется. Проверяющий сможет запустить только jar и иметь доступ ко всем сохранённым ранее данным. Кроме того, хранить данные в БД - это хорошая практика. Это позволяет пользоваться sql-запросами, удобно производить фильтрацию данных и быстро получать и сохранять данные.

Comment: Спасибо, также подумал об этой базе. Пока что сделал чтение/запись в файл, но позже думаю перейти на БД.

Answer (score 0):

Для такой задачи неплохо подойдет SQLite. Это БД которая подключается одним файлом

Comment: Спасибо, хорошая идея!

Comment: В JDK уже есть JavaDB. Зачем какой-то SQLite?

Comment: @IgorKudryashov ответил по своему опыту